# How do I send a condition test to a Javascript function and not only it's result?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I had the idea about making a small jQuery plugin but there's something I don't know how to do it without having to rely on `eval`.

Here's the code:

```
            var testMe = 1;

            $.extend({
                once : function( condition, duration, callback) {
                    window[ "once" ] = window.setTimeout(function() {
                        if ( condition )
                        {
                            callback.apply();

                            window.clearTimeout( window[ "once" ] );
                        } else {
                            window[ "once" ] = window.setTimeout( arguments.callee, duration * 1000 );
                        }
                    }, duration * 1000 );
                }
            });

            $.once(testMe == 2, 5, function() {
                alert("Match!");
            });
```

It looks like when `$.once()` is being called, the first parameter is then evaluated and only it's value at this time is sent to the condition parameter. The only way I found is to send it as a string:

`$.once("testMe == 2" ...` and use `if ( eval( condition ) )`

Is there another way withing the use of `eval` ?

Thank you.

**Edit: here is the a final version of the plugin:**

```
            var testOne = 1,
                testTwo = 1;

            $.extend({
                once : function( name, conditionFn, duration, callback) {
                    if ( typeof duration ==  "function" )
                    {
                        callback = duration;
                        duration = 5;
                    }

                    window[ "once" + name ] = window.setInterval(function() {
                        if ( conditionFn() )
                        {
                            callback();

                            window.clearInterval( window[ "once" + name ] );
                        }
                    }, duration * 1000 );
                }
            });


            //Examples
            $.once("testOne", function() {
                return testOne == 2
            }, 2, function() {
                alert("testOne == 1");
            });

            $.once("testTwo", function() {
                return testTwo == 2
            }, 2, function() {
                alert("testTwo == 1");
            });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct; the parameters are evaluated and then passed. I would not recommend using `eval` unless you really know what you're doing, and there's a compelling reason to do so.

Instead, pass a **predicate** (a function which returns a boolean) to your plugin. Every time you want to do the check, invoke the function:

var testMe = 1;

```
$.extend({
    once : function(predicate, duration, callback) {
        window.once = window.setInterval(function() {
            if (predicate()) {
                window.clearInterval(window.once);
                callback();
            }
        }, duration * 1000);
    }
});

$.once(function () { return testMe == 2; }, 5, function() {
    alert("Match!");
});
```

**N.B.** I replaced your repeated `setTimeout` calls with a self-cancelling `setInterval()`. Also, you were invoking the `callback` with `callback.apply()`, but there is no reason to do this. You can directly call it with `()`, as the above code does.

Answer (score 1):

Send a function that returns the result of the comparison:

```
var testMe = 1;

$.extend({
                    // receive the function
    once : function( conditionFn, duration, callback) {
        window[ "once" ] = window.setTimeout(function() {

                // execute the function
            if ( conditionFn() )
            {
                callback.apply();

                window.clearTimeout( window[ "once" ] );
            } else {
                window[ "once" ] = window.setTimeout( arguments.callee, duration * 1000 );
            }
        }, duration * 1000 );
    }
});
        // send a function
$.once(function(){return testMe == 2;}, 5, function() {
    alert("Match!");
});
```

Comment: Don't you mean "if( condition() )"?

Comment: This works! But I dont find it very "user-friendly" having to ask the user to passes an anonymous function which return a condition to a function. But I guess it's the only solution I have.